# Magento 2 Server Side Compilation and Grunt Result in 404 Errors in Developer Mode

Tags: magento2, grunt

I am currently working on a theme that I have used and have been changing the templates and styles following the detailed guides over at the Magento2 site.

However, I am really struggling to make progress and am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

From my understanding of the documentation I can use server side compilation and Grunt to make the changes necessary to progress my developments.

This sounds great, so I installed Grunt and that is working fine, but my issue is that I keep getting loads of 404 errors around pub/static files not existing.

This is strange as from my understanding these files should be generated automatically.

What seems to work is when I run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

But, I don't want to do that each time and it also means that when I run:

```
grunt watch:theme_name
```

No changes are detected.

A couple of notes to try and help understand where I have come from:

- I am in developer mode
- I have cleared the contents of var and pub/static
- I am on Magento 2.0.7 updated via composer
- I have run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- I also get the same 404 errors when I access the admin area
- I have run grunt refresh, grunt exec:all and grunt less to compile all less, but still have the same issues
- Some digging around seemed to point to symlinks, but I have not been able to work it out

I am sure there is one small thing I am missing or not doing. If anyone could help that would be great as I am tearing my hair out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`  to generate files for admin.
After you run `grunt clean` or `grunt exec` pub/static files are deleted.

Also make sure you have right file permissions for `pub/static`.

What I'm doing on my localhost(windows 7) to develop a theme is following:

- if I'm getting erros in browser console for missing files I execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy locale_locale`
- run grunt `exec:my_theme`
- run grunt `watch:my_theme`

If I'm adding some `css` files to theme I need to re-do static-content:deploy again in order to move this files to `pub/static`

Comment: thanks for the advice. It looks like the step to deploy again when adding a less file has done the trick and now the 'grunt watch' task is working. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @AdamStacey you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run your console as administrator, I never use deploy.

Grunt clean
Grunt exec:themename
Grunt less:themename or Grunt watch